# Распределение данных в DB

Tags: mysql, sql, база-данных

Я разрабатываю проект, в котором пользователь сможет добавлять свою информацию (может быть список, состоящий из нескольких десятков или сотен отдельных строк). Мне нужно сохранить эту информацию в базу данных (информация не о пользователях, а строки, которые пользователь сам добавляет), но я не знаю как лучше к этому подойти. Думаю, создать одну таблицу для всех пользователей, где будет находиться вся информация пользователей, но в таком случае она будет громоздкой, либо создать таблицу для каждого пользователя, где будет храниться только его информация, но тогда таблиц в базе данных будет слишком много. Я новичок в этом деле, поэтому не знаю как поступить. По моему мнению, было бы удобнее использовать таблицу для информации, добавленной каждым пользователем.

Answer (score 0):

Громоздкой - это сколько? MySQL спокойно работает с данными в 1 - 2 GB, если уверен, что база быстро станет больше 10 GB и более ~150 млн. записей в одной таблице, то необходимо использовать NoSQL базу данных, к примеру MongoDB, либо Redis. Не совсем понятен ваш вопрос на самом деле, если есть способ разделить информацию - то её можно разделить, если в будущем будет удобно получить необходимые данные из другой таблицы. Но опять же, зависит от типов данных, их количества в одном поле и т.д

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Хочу разделить данные путём создания таблицы для каждого пользователя с конкретно его информацией (строками, которые он вводит), чтобы структурировать данные. Будет ли "адекватным" такой путь?

Comment: Новую таблицу для каждого пользователя? Вряд ли это будет хорошим решением.

Comment: Вот и я об этом. Спасибо за ответы.